# Golang Typecasting

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion, dice

I have specific questions for my project

input = "3d6"

I want to convert this string some parts to integer. For instance I want to use input[0] like integer.
How can I do this?

Comment: i, err := strconv.Atoi(input[:1])

Comment: Go doesn't have type casting. You're also not talking about typecasting at all. You're talking about type conversion and string parsing.

Comment: More important: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here:

### How to convert a string to an integer

The most straightforward method is the [`Atoi`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) (ASCII to integer) function in the `strconv` package., which will take a string of numeric characters and coerce them into an integer for you.

### How to extract meaningful components of a known string pattern

In order to use `strconv.Atoi`, we need the numeric characters of the input by themselves. There's lots of ways to slice and dice a string.

- You can just grab the first and last characters directly - `input[:1]` and `input[2:]` are the ticket.
- You could split the string into two strings on the character "d". Look at the [`split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) method, a member of the `strings` package.
- For more complex problems in this space, *[regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)* are used. They're a way to define a pattern the computer can look for. For example, the regular expression `^x(\d+)$` will match on any string that starts with the character `x` and is followed by one or more numeric characters. It will provide direct access to the numeric characters it found by themselves.

  - Go has first class support for regular expressions via its [`regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp) package.